# Why one need different table aliases If the table appears more than once in the FROM clause?

Tags: sql, join

Currently I'm reading a book about SQL which provide following explanation:

> you will need to give each instance of the branch table a different alias so that the server knows which one you are referring to in the various clauses.

But I can't understand why it's not possible to `JOIN` columns from the exact same table while using different `ON` clauses? Why server need to create second instance of the table and then distinguish them from each other?

Comment: It is possible to `JOIN` to a table multiple times, but you need to name them differently in your query so that the server knows which join to get results from.

Comment: In some cases it would be possible for the parser to understand that you are joining two tables, and so `ON ID = ID` could be made to work. However `ON ID = ParentID` would still be ambiguous, as would queries with additional tables (either the same table or another table with columns named the same) . Also, errors in very complex queries would lead to confusion and the question "is the parser understanding my intent?" So, sticking to a syntax which allows these issues to be resolved simply is better for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the parser knows which table you're referring to when referencing the columns in the JOIN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Person      // child
INNER JOIN Person         // parent
ON Person.ID = Person.ParentID          // which table goes with which column?
```

or when using additional columns in the join:

```
SELECT * FROM Person      // child
INNER JOIN Person         // parent
ON Person.ID = Person.ParentID          // which table goes with which column?
    AND Person.Name = "John"  // child or parent?
```

or in a WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM Person      // child
INNER JOIN Person         // parent
ON Person.ID = Person.ParentID
WHERE Name = "John"       // child or parent?
```

Or when adding a third table

```
SELECT * FROM Person      // child
INNER JOIN Person         // parent
ON Person.ID = Person.ParentID
INNER JOIN Address
ON Person.AddressID = Address.AddressID  // child or parent?
```

or when specifying columns in the result:

```
SELECT Name    // Child or Parent?
FROM Person      // child
INNER JOIN Person         // parent
ON Person.ID = Person.ParentID          // which table goes with which column?
```

Bottom line - there are too many places where the context *cannot* be assumed, so aliases are required.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person AS Child
INNER JOIN Person AS Parent
ON Parent.ID = Child.ParentID
```

Note that you do not "create [a] second instance" but just reference the same table twice.  This may be what you meant but I wanted to be sure you understood that no data is copied or replicated; your're just referencing a table to itself.

Comment: I can't see any problem with 3rd line of your example. It's natural to assume that `ID = ParentID` is equivalent to `Person.ID = Person.ParentID`.

Comment: Added some more examples.

Comment: Either you misunderstood or the book is completely wrong - joining tables does NOT create a temporary copy of either table. It _may_ create _some_ temporary data to improve the lookup performance, but that would be true whether or not you were forced to use an alias.

Comment: @D Stanley I need to think a bit about your examples and then I will come up with example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. I understood your examples. Can I ask a question about JOINs? I mean that as far as I understood SELECT statement create temporary result table and with each  JOIN we add columns to that result table. Am I right?

Comment: in a sense - if the result is a table then that table is probably in some sort of temporary memory, but it's not a "temporary table" in the sense that it's physically stored like temporary tables created by users are.  There may be some scenarios where the query just passes data straight from the source to the result, but that's an implementation detail.

Comment: Don't concern yourself with how the database is doing it's work internally unless you are deep deep into optimization or are writing database engines yourself. Even standard optimization is somewhat abstracted - you are concerned with least data and least number of steps and cost of those steps, but not how it actually achieves them.

Comment: When writing queries you worry about syntax and describing the problem correctly and efficiently in SQL to get the correct result. In the case of joins, accept that the database engine wants aliases so the query is clear and it understands what you want. That doesn't constrain *how* it obtains the answer internally, just what it understands you want it to give you. In the case of a self-join it _may_ even be able to obtain the result with a single pass through the table (or just the index). Again - leave the *HOW* up to the database and concentrate on the *WHAT*.

Comment: @Turophile While I agree with the premise of starting with a _working_ query that's easy to understand - there is still a benefit to optimization (to a point).  You can make a significant difference in how a query performs by making slight modifications to a query that may not seem obvious.  Again, I'm not disputing your main point, but leave _some_ room for optimization.